# I have confusion in using present and past tenses in writing about history of english literature.please this for me

Tags: verbs, tenses

American literature is also divided into periods for convenience because of its common traits and characteristics. Naturally, the first phase of American literature is of colonial literature. This phase dawns with the beginning of America and covers the time period until 1776. Second is the age of reason that opens in late 1770s and remains until 1800. During this age, authors focused on reasoning rather than facts taught by authorities. After age of reason, romanticism replaces reality. Romanticism begins in 1800 and lasts until 1850. Gothic literature also stirs in this period as a sub genre of romanticism. This genre also includes the element of supernatural in literature.  Then is the era of transcendentalism (1840-1855). This period stresses on individualism and self-reliance. During the same period, anti-transcendentalism is taking place. Three simultaneously literary moments remains in the period from 1865 to 1015. First is the moment of realism.  Realism replaces romanticism. This is the reversal of objectivity in literature. Naturalism accompanies realism. The defining feature of naturalism is that it highlights forces that are not under control of human beings and it underlines pessimism. At the same time, regionalism is in fashion.  Writing about the specific geographical areas is the prominent feature of this literature. An epoch of experimentation with stream of consciousness, fragmentation and interior monologue follows age of realism. This period of unique style is the period of modernism (1915-1946). Literature since 1946 is called contemporary literature. We have plethora of genres in contemporary American literature. It includes fiction, fantasy, science fiction, horror, political writings, romantics, plays, poems and many other experimental writings.

Comment: This is so wordy...

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that we are neither a proofreading service nor a writers workshop, though we can help you suss out the finer points of grammar or usage if you have a question about a specific problem. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance. For help with proofreading, you might try lang-8.com.

Answer (score 2):

I take it from the title, you want to know why you can use the present tense:  "Second is the age of reason that *opens* in late 1770s and *remains* until 1800."  After all, we're well past 1800, so why don't those verbs have to be in the past tense:  "*opened* in the late 1770s," "*remained* until 1800"?

This use of the present tense is called the "historical present," and it's often used in historical narrative.  The narrator places himself in the time he's describing and writes as though the events were contemporaneous.